# Blazor startup project setup errors

Tags: c#, blazor

So i wanted to get starting with .NET blazor and for some reason i have compiler errors. The program works as expected if i run it tough, But the errors bugs me.
The steps i did are:

- Downloaded and installed latest .net core 3.0,
- Installed the Blazor templates using `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview6.19307.2`
- Enabled preview features of the .net at visual studio
- Installed Blazor extension from the Visual Studio Marketplace

And i get this error [image]

**The error says "the name '' does not exist in current context**

**UPDATE**
I installed visual studio 2019 preview as @Henry Rodriguez suggested, The errors were indeed gone, But when i added a new `Todo.razor` page (as in this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.0) 
I got the errors again,
What could be the solution to this problem?
[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you to delete this app, reboot, and create this app afresh. Hope this works... You may as well provide a link to your app...

Answer (score 0):

Blazor is meant to be used with Visual Studio Preview versions [image]

You can find it here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

You can have several different VS versions installed side by side without problems, they won't interfere between them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, In case someone having the same problem - What happen is that i needed to add a .razor page to the project. When i right clicked and choose 'Add razor page' from the menu it actually added a .cshtml page. What i did then was just adding a text file which ends with .razor